# Why do these python variables share the same ID

Tags: python

Why do 2 python variables share the same ID after they are initialised with the same value?  Surely they are 2 independent objects...unless it is an efficiency saving?

```
name1="Steve"
name2="Steve"
id(name1), id(name2)
```

Outputs the same ID for both objects?!

Comment: CPython interns strings that are valid identifiers - this is an implementation detail, and shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: And to add on to what @jonrsharpe said, it doesn't matter because strings are immutable, so it's not like you can accidentally change the object referred to by `name1` and alter the object referred to by `name2`.  If you do `name1 = name1.lower()`, `name2` will still refer to the uppercase `"Steve"` because `name1` now refers to a different string.